# Automount NTFS HDDs in specific locations and share them in LAN

Tags: fstab, shared-folders, ntfs-3g

### O.S: Raspbmc

I need to share 4 HDDs over my LAN, but the fstab I wrote does't work as I aspect.

---

### Edit1~

Here's the part of fstab made for those HDDs:

```
#External HHDs
LABEL=Incompleted\040Seasons     /media/IncompletedSeasons ntfs-3g  auto,rw,exec,async,dmask=0002,fmask=0003,uid=1000,gid=1000  0  0
LABEL=Films                      /media/Films              ntfs-3g  auto,rw,exec,async,dmask=0002,fmask=0003,uid=1000,gid=1000  0  0
LABEL=Music\040and\040Animation  /media/MusicAndAnimation  ntfs-3g  auto,rw,exec,async,dmask=0002,fmask=0003,uid=1000,gid=1000  0  0
LABEL=Completed\040Seasons       /media/CompletedSeasons   ntfs-3g  auto,rw,exec,async,dmask=0002,fmask=0003,uid=1000,gid=1000  0  0
```

They are named correctly, and folders for mountpoints already exists:

```
root@raspbmc:/home/pi# ls -la /media/
total 24
drwxrwxr-x  6 root root 4096 Jul 27 19:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Jul 13 19:20 ..
drwxrwxr-x  2 pi   pi   4096 Jul 27 19:08 CompletedSeasons
drwxrwxr-x  2 pi   pi   4096 Jul 27 19:07 Films
drwxrwxr-x  2 pi   pi   4096 Jul 27 19:07 IncompletedSeasons
drwxrwxr-x  2 pi   pi   4096 Jul 27 19:07 MusicAndAnimation
```

At this point, I aspect that throwing `mount -a` will mount those 4 HDDs, in those 4 folders with permissions are wrote in the fstab.
Let's try:

```
root@raspbmc:/home/pi# mount -a
mount: devpts already mounted or /dev/pts busy
ntfs-3g: Failed to access volume 'LABEL=Music and Animation': No such file or directory

ntfs-3g 2012.1.15AR.5 external FUSE 29 - Third Generation NTFS Driver
                Configuration type 7, XATTRS are on, POSIX ACLS are on

Copyright (C) 2005-2007 Yura Pakhuchiy
Copyright (C) 2006-2009 Szabolcs Szakacsits
Copyright (C) 2007-2011 Jean-Pierre Andre
Copyright (C) 2009 Erik Larsson

Usage:    ntfs-3g [-o option[,...]] <device|image_file> <mount_point>

Options:  ro (read-only mount), remove_hiberfile, uid=, gid=,
          umask=, fmask=, dmask=, streams_interface=.
          Please see the details in the manual (type: man ntfs-3g).

Example: ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt/windows

News, support and information:  http://tuxera.com
root@raspbmc:/home/pi# ls -la /media/
total 204
drwxrwxr-x  6 root root 4096 Jul 27 19:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Jul 13 19:20 ..
drwxrwxr-x  1 pi   pi   4096 Jul 19 17:17 CompletedSeasons
drwxrwxr-x  1 pi   pi   4096 Jul 12 21:58 Films
drwxrwxr-x  1 pi   pi   4096 Jul 27 18:51 IncompletedSeasons
drwxrwxr-x  2 pi   pi   4096 Jul 27 19:07 MusicAndAnimation
```

It works! Don't mind the 4th failed, it's turned off...
Then I reboot the device, and this is the result:

```
root@raspbmc:/home/pi# ls -la /media/
total 152
drwxrwxr-x  8 root root 4096 Jul 27 19:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Jul 13 19:20 ..
drwx------  1 pi   pi   4096 Jul 19 17:17 Completed Seasons
drwxrwxr-x  2 pi   pi   4096 Jul 27 19:08 CompletedSeasons
drwxrwxr-x  2 pi   pi   4096 Jul 27 19:07 Films
drwx------  1 pi   pi   4096 Jul 27 18:51 Incompleted Seasons
drwxrwxr-x  2 pi   pi   4096 Jul 27 19:07 IncompletedSeasons
drwxrwxr-x  2 pi   pi   4096 Jul 27 19:07 MusicAndAnimation
```

Usually these new folders are mounted normally, but the olders are empty.
Did I forget doing something? Did I make any mistake? Can you help me please?

---

### Edit2~

I tried renamig folders and fstab mountpoints with the same name as the labels, and, after the reboot, the result was something like this:

```
root@raspbmc:/home/pi# ls -la /media/
total 152
drwxrwxr-x  8 root root 4096 Jul 27 19:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Jul 13 19:20 ..
drwx------  1 pi   pi   4096 Jul 19 17:17 Completed Seasons_
drwxrwxr-x  2 pi   pi   4096 Jul 27 19:08 Completed Seasons
drwx------  1 pi   pi   4096 Jul 19 17:17 Films
drwx------  1 pi   pi   4096 Jul 27 18:51 Incompleted Seasons_
drwxrwxr-x  2 pi   pi   4096 Jul 27 19:07 Incompleted Seasons
drwxrwxr-x  2 pi   pi   4096 Jul 27 19:07 Music and Animation
```

I thought the system hadn't enought privileges to use my folders as mountpoints, but I don't understand where to fix it (if I need this).
Could it be caused by the use of 'pi' user instead of 'root' one? (`uid=1000` and `gid=1000` are both refered to pi user and group).
Samba and XBMC are forced to look into those folders for my media stuff, could it be part of the problem?

---

### Edit3~

I tried to use UUID instead of Labels, nothing changed. But, this time, I didn't mount them manually and just reboot, and I noticed that NOTHING happened. No mounted HDDs, no new folders, and the old one is perfectly the same as before (empty and with same privileges).

It seems fstab doesn't work at all, so I checkd its mods:

```
root@raspbmc:/home/pi# ls -la /etc/fstab
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1347 Aug  4 09:31 /etc/fstab
```

Just to try, I changed it in:

```
root@raspbmc:/home/pi# ls -la /etc/fstab
-rwxrwxr-- 1 root root 1347 Aug  4 09:41 /etc/fstab
```

And reboot, but nothing new.
I cleaned the fstab a little bit, to test with just 1 HDD at a time, with this build:

```
UUID=646ADB4C6ADB199E     /media/IncompletedSeasons ntfs-3g  auto,rw,exec,async,dmask=0002,fmask=0003,uid=1000,gid=1000  0  0
```

Of course, the UUID is correct:

```
root@raspbmc:/home/pi# blkid
/dev/mmcblk0p1: UUID="CEC6-297F" TYPE="vfat"
/dev/mmcblk0p2: UUID="f5035424-d974-4c50-b749-76d000ba1ee6" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="IncompletedSeasons" UUID="646ADB4C6ADB199E" TYPE="ntfs"
```

Nobody wants to join me here?

Comment: Are those new directories mounted?

Comment: Something changes everytime. Sometimes they are mounted, sometimes Films is not but the others are mounted, sometimes I boot my device and nothing happen (there are only my folders, empty)

Comment: Please post Ubuntu version you are using.

Comment: This is a Raspbmc system, which is based on Debian.